# Insert multiple rows into a SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I've written the following C# code to insert rows (that a user enters from a web application) into a SQL database.  How does this code look?  Is there a better, more efficient way to accomplish the task?

```
public void UpdateDeviceStatus(string[] deviceId, byte[] status, string userId, string[] remarks, DateTime dateTurnin)
{                
        if (deviceId.Length != status.Length || status.Length != remarks.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid arguments passed to UpdateDeviceStatus: deviceId, status, and remarks must contain the same number of entries.");
        if (deviceId.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("UpdateDeviceStatus expects to update status for at least one deviceId, but an empty array was passed in.");

        // Build the SQL statement
        StringBuilder sbSql = new StringBuilder();
        sbSql.Append(@"INSERT INTO AT_Event_History(deviceId,parentCode,statusCode,remarks,userId,whenEntered) VALUES");
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceId.Length; i++)
        {
            string values = string.Format("({0},0,{1},{2},{3},{4}),",
                new string[] { "@deviceId" + i.ToString(), "@statusCode" + i.ToString(), "@remarks" + i.ToString(), "@userId", "@whenEntered" });
            sbSql.Append(values);
        }
        string sql = sbSql.ToString();
        sql = sql.TrimEnd(','); // remove the trailing comma ','

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("AssetTrackConnection");

        DbCommand command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = sql;

        // Add in parameters
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@userId", DbType.AnsiString, userId);
        db.AddInParameter(command, "@whenEntered", DbType.Date, dateTurnin);
        for (int j = 0; j < deviceId.Length; j++)
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "@deviceId" + j.ToString(), DbType.Guid, new Guid(deviceId[j]));
            db.AddInParameter(command, "@statusCode" + j.ToString(), DbType.Byte, status[j]);
            db.AddInParameter(command, "@remarks" + j.ToString(), DbType.AnsiString, remarks[j]);
        }

        // Execute the statement.
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(command);    
}
```

As you can see, I am looping to add db parameters to hold the value for each row.  I think that there may be a better way to do this.

Comment: I just fixed my question.  I'm sorry for the headaches caused by the ****ed part where I mixed up the question and the code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are building a dynamic insert statement with parametrized values.  This works and there's nothing wrong with this method.  It may even be the best method for your circumstance.  It works well when your table is "small".  I have a rather large database which grows monotonically.  We keep adding rows and never remove any.  When your table grows beyond a certain point that is specific to your table design, inserts get very slow.  At this point, you will want to consider using the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.  You insert the values into a DataTable and then do a bulk insert.  This is much faster because it uses a SQL Server specific method of loading data faster.  The [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) link has sample code.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to look into this `SqlBulkCopy` class and try it on some of my pages.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, starting with SQL 2008 stored procedures support [Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSharpAndTableValueParams.aspx), which let you pass a multi-column, multi-row recordset as an argument to the stored proc.

This can be useful in situations where (because of its limitations) BulkCopy is not a feasible solution. In particular, because it's "one table at a time".